# PHP - How to make pretty urls using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I'm wondering how to make my URLs pretty and SEO friendly and also work with PHP code.

Currently everything works fine (for example example.com/test/ is fine and works).

However when I have `error.php?id=404`, I want it to go to `/error/404/`.

How do I do this?

My current .htaccess is...

```
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to let the framework handle it, or your can read more about mod_rewrite [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

EDIT:

the underscore in url is not SEO friendly

Comment: I'm not using a framework and I don't understand the link you gave me. I'm kind of new to all this and can't figure out how to fix the end bits of the urls so I'm not sure where to look on the above site.

Comment: @Dan no problem, hope it helps !