# How to make my website url SEO friendly and tell google bots that there is an important content

Tags: php, web-config

I am using a Windows Hosting. But my website is written in `php`. Sometimes I have to get contents from `MySQL` database using an `id` like...

```
<a href="view.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>
```

and the url shown in the browser address bar something like below

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/view.php?id=1025896
```

You can easily understand the above url.

My questions are...

1. Is there any way to make the url SEO friendly ?

Like

`http://www.mywebsite.com/view/1025896/`

and

2. How to tell the `Google` bots or other crawler that there is an important content in this link `(as this link is getting content directly from database using an id)`.

I have seen [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496462/php-how-to-make-pretty-urls-using-mod-rewrite) but this is written for `.htaccess` which will not work in `IIS`

Comment: Both URLs are the same, no one is better or worse regarding SEO.

Comment: Thw magic my content is special tag :-)